# Поиск и замена невидимого неразрывного пробела в базе данных

Tags: sql, oracle

По интеграции в базу данных передается неразрывный пробел, который не виден глазами.
Например текст - описание товара:

```
Обои компакт-винил на флизелиновой основе 1,06х10,05 м Elysium Грани фон Е700703 КПП
```

В результате чего HTML формы отображающие это описание выглядят некорректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел что код этого пробела в Unicode - \00A0 или &#160 (приходилось вставлять в Excel соответствующую формулу.

Чтобы найти все строки в базе данных с пробелом мне пригодился следующий код:

```
select article, description from art_t where REGEXP_LIKE(description,'[' ||unistr('\00A0')|| ']');
```

Чтобы исправить ситуацию с формами составил следующий скрипт:

```
update art_t
set artbez = REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '[' ||unistr('\00A0')|| ']', ' ',1)
 where REGEXP_LIKE(description,'[' ||unistr('\00A0')|| ']')
```

Это решение сработало, но решать лучше конечно лучше в первоисточнике из которого приходит в интеграцию такая "ошибка".

Comment: Повесьте на таблицу триггер, который будет перед добавлением данных убирать этот символ или на серверной части можно обрабатывать поле перед update. Одинокий update для исправления таблицы это хорошо, однако это не полечит новые вставки данных и вам придется его выполнять постоянно.

Comment: @Mik - Я раньше использовал `chr(49824)`, но `unistr('\00A0')` смотрится более понятно.  Шпасиба!

Comment: а зачем тут скобки  [ ] ? `'[' ||unistr('\00A0')|| ']'`